# How do you use a separate .apk file in your android app?

Tags: android, imageview, tiff

I'm trying to display a .tiff image in an android app and it looks like .tiffs are not supported. The number one recommendation people have been recommending is to use Tiffonandroid (a google code project). Is there a basic way to incorporate a separate .apk file into an android app? I've tried to find resources online, but have come up dry. If that it more complicated then I'm imagining it being does anyone know of any .tiff converters or view libraries that would also work?

Comment: It doesn't look like tiffonandroid is an app.  It's a library.  You'd just import it like other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries are not .apk files, they are projects or modules of code for you to use in your project. You can import them into your project and many libraries will give directions on how.